# how to run virtual hosts configured URL on Mobile using XAMPP

Tags: mobile, xampp, virtualhost

I have configured the following domain URL on my machine

```
URL: local.abc.com
```

with the following settings on `httpd-vhosts.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\www\abc"
ServerName local.abc.com
```

on my host file

```
192.168.1.127   local.abc.com
```

**Q:** how i can run `local.abc.com` URL on my `iPhone` and on other mobile devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to iPhone' 
`Settings -> Wi-Fi`

select your wifi connection scroll down and change`HTTP PROXY` to manual and give `Server` the IP address `192.168.1.127` and port to 80 (or whatever you have used.)

Comment: it there any way to connect from Android Phone?